# XPath Expression: Select elements between A HREF="expr" tags

Tags: html, select, xpath, tags

I didn't found an explicit way to select all nodes that exist between two anchors (`<a></a>` tag pair) in an HTML file.

The first anchor has the following format:

```
<a href="file://START..."></a>
```

Second anchor:

```
<a href="file://END..."></a>
```

I've verified that both can be selected using starts-with (note that I'm using HTML Agility Pack):

```
HtmlNode n0 = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[starts-with(@href,'file://START')]"));
HtmlNode n1 = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[starts-with(@href,'file://END')]"));
```

With this in mind, and with my amateurish XPath skills, I wrote the following expression to get all tags between the two anchors:

```
html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[not(following-sibling::a[starts-with(@href,'file://START0')]) and not (preceding-sibling::a[starts-with(@href,'file://END0')])]");
```

This seems to work, but selects all HTML document!

I need to, for example for the following HTML fragment:

```
<html>
...

<a href="file://START0"></a>
<p>First nodes</p>
<p>First nodes
    <span>X</span>
</p>
<p>First nodes</p>
<a href="file://END0"></a>

...
</html>
```

remove both anchors, the three P (including of course the inner SPAN).

Any way to do this?

I don't know if XPath 2.0 offers better ways to achieve this.

***EDIT (special case!) ***

I should also handle the case where:

"Select tags between X and X', where X is `<p><a href="file://..."></a></p>`"

So instead of:

```
<a href="file://START..."></a>
<!-- xhtml to be extracted -->
<a href="file://END..."></a>
```

I should handle also:

```
<p>
  <a href="file://START..."></a>
</p>
<!-- xhtml to be extracted -->

<p>
  <a href="file://END..."></a>
</p>
```

Thank you very much, again.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two solutions (XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0), explanation and their verification with XSLT as the host of XPath.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use this XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
//a[starts-with(@href,'file://START')]/following-sibling::node()
     [count(.| //a[starts-with(@href,'file://END')]/preceding-sibling::node())
     =
      count(//a[starts-with(@href,'file://END')]/preceding-sibling::node())
     ]
```

**Or, use this XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
    //a[starts-with(@href,'file://START')]/following-sibling::node()
  intersect
    //a[starts-with(@href,'file://END')]/preceding-sibling::node()
```

The XPath 2.0 expression uses the XPath 2.0 `intersect` operator.

The XPath 1.0 expression uses the Kayessian (after @Michael Kay) formula for the intersectioon of two node-sets:

```
$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

**Verification with XSLT**:

This XSLT 1.0 transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "    //a[starts-with(@href,'file://START')]/following-sibling::node()
         [count(.| //a[starts-with(@href,'file://END')]/preceding-sibling::node())
         =
          count(//a[starts-with(@href,'file://END')]/preceding-sibling::node())
         ]
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<html>...
    <a href="file://START0"></a>
    <p>First nodes</p>
    <p>First nodes    
        <span>X</span>
    </p>
    <p>First nodes</p>
    <a href="file://END0"></a>...
</html>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<p>First nodes</p>
<p>First nodes    
        <span>X</span>
</p>
<p>First nodes</p>
```

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  " //a[starts-with(@href,'file://START')]/following-sibling::node()
   intersect
    //a[starts-with(@href,'file://END')]/preceding-sibling::node()
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document (above) again produces exactly the wanted result**.

Comment: +1. Even if it's clear to me when the XPath 1.0 Kayessian formula comes in help, it is always hard to me realize how to apply it in the various situations; while I can easily read the XPath 2.0 intersection. This example however is really useful.

Comment: @empo: You can visualize both of them with the XPath Visualizer :)

Comment: I'm surprised HtmlAgilityPack SelectNodes method does not support XPath 2.0.

Comment: @Hernan: There are few XPath 2.0 implementations and they usually come as part either of XSLT 2.0 processors or XQuery processors -- almost never standalone. We have a technology gap here and iti s going to widen as XPath 3.0 is moving towards becoming an official standard.

Comment: Dimitry, I've added a special case that I should handle :P

Comment: @Hernan, I've added an answer covering your "special case". Cheers

Comment: @Hernan: This is as easy as the first solution -- again expressing the intersection of two node-sets. You only need to define these node-sets, and this isn't difficult -- as @empo has already shown.

Answer (score 2):

> *I've added a special case that I should handle*

To handle this special case you can work in the same way, I mean use the Kayessian (and use XPath Visualizer as well ;-)). The intersecting node-sets change as follows:

**Intersecting node-set C**

```
    "//p[.//a[starts-with(@href,'file://START')]]
         /following-sibling::node()"
```

All following sibling of `p` containing `a` *START*.

**Intersecting node-set D**

```
"./following-sibling::p[.//a[starts-with(@href,'file://END')]]
    /preceding-sibling::node())"
```

All preceding siblings of `p` containing `a` *END* and following sibling of current `p`

---

Now you can perform the intersection as:

### **C ∩ D**

That is

```
    "//p[.//a[starts-with(@href,'file://START')]]
            /following-sibling::node()[
            count(.| ./following-sibling::p
                     [.//a[starts-with(@href,'file://END')]]
                       /preceding-sibling::node())
            =
            count(./following-sibling::p
                   [.//a[starts-with(@href,'file://END')]]
                     /preceding-sibling::node())
            ]"
```

---

If you need to manage both situations, you can proceed with the union of the intersecting node-sets as

### **(A ∩ B) ∪ (C ∩ D)**

Where:

- The XPath union operator `|` must be used:
- the node-sets A e B are already showed in the @Dimitre'answer
- the node-sets C e D are those showed in my answer.

Comment: awesome thank you very much! Seems XPath 2.0 makes those set operations much easier, unfortunately there is no 2.0 support in .NET 3!

Comment: It seems. You are allwed to write `$n1 intersect $n2` in place of `$n1[count(.|$n2)=count($n2)]`. The selection of the node-sets is tricky anyway.

Comment: @Dimitre: Well, this means I was _absolutely_ good! :D Thanks